# Notif user of his favourite match

Tags: java, android

I want to create app of hockey results. On home page, user select his favorite team and than he can see in fragment Future Matches - matches of his favorite team. 
After this, he can select his favorite match (by click on match) and than, If score is changed in this match, user get notification about changed score.
But I have problem, because when I see future matches, after click on match, application drop. 
I don´t have any idea about solve this problem. 
I need help with this.

```
public class Future_matches extends Fragment {

    private static Future_matches fragment;
    private int favorite_team_id;
    private SharedPreferences sp;

    private RecyclerView rv_futureMatches;
    //   private FutureMatchesAdapter adapter;
    private List<FutureMatchModel> teams;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    List<Thread> listOfActiveThreads;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter<FutureMatchesHolder> adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public Future_matches() {
    }

    public static Future_matches newInstance() {
        if (fragment == null)
            fragment = new Future_matches();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listOfActiveThreads = new ArrayList<>();
        sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Tools.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        favorite_team_id = sp.getInt(Tools.FAVORITE_TEAM_ID, -1);
        ed = sp.edit();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.future_matches, container, false);
        rv_futureMatches = rootview.findViewById(R.id.rv_future_matches);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        //  rv_futureMatches.setLayoutManager(lm);
        //  rv_futureMatches.setHasFixedSize(true);

        if (favorite_team_id == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.warning_future_matches_choose_favorite_team, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Tools.getApi().getFutureMatches(favorite_team_id, "2018-12-27", "2019-05-12").enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        teams = JsonTools.convertJsonToFutureMatches(response.body());
                        // JsonObject data = response.body();

                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());


                        //         adapter = new FutureMatchesAdapter(JsonTools.convertJsonToFutureMatches(data), new WeakReference<Context>(getActivity()));


                        adapter = new FutureMatchesAdapter(teams, new WeakReference<Context>(getActivity()), new FutureMatchesAdapter.TeamClickHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(int id) {
                                takeCareOfChanges(id);
                            }
                        });

                        rv_futureMatches.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        rv_futureMatches.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        rv_futureMatches.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
        return rootview;
    }

    private boolean isItemInList(int id) {
        if (sp.contains(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES)) {
            Set<String> result = sp.getStringSet(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES, null);
            if (result.contains(Integer.toString(id))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else
            return false;

    }

    private void takeCareOfChanges(int id) {
        if (sp.contains(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES)) {
            Set<String> result = sp.getStringSet(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES, null);
            if (isItemInList(id)) {
                result.remove(Integer.toString(id));
                ed.putStringSet(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES, result);
                quitService(id);
            } else {
                result.add(Integer.toString(id));
                ed.putStringSet(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES, result);
                launchService(id);
            }
        } else {
            Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
            result.add(Integer.toString(id));
            ed.putStringSet(Tools.PREFS_PICKED_GAMES, result);
            launchService(id);
        }
        ed.apply();
    }

    private void launchService(final int id){
                getActivity().startService(new Intent().putExtra(Tools.INTENT_EXTRA_ID,id));
    }
    private void quitService(int id){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction(Tools.INTENT_ACTION_STOP_SERVICE).putExtra(Tools.INTENT_EXTRA_ID,id));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GameChangeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "GameChangeService";
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Handler h;
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    Notification notif;
    NotificationManager notifManager;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    private Runnable r;
    private int id;

    private String CHANNEL_ID = "ID";
    private int notifId = 1000;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sp = getSharedPreferences(Tools.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ed = sp.edit();
        notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        h = new Handler();
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Tools.INTENT_ACTION_STOP_SERVICE));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        id = intent.getIntExtra(Tools.INTENT_EXTRA_ID, -1);
        if (id == -1) {
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doStuff(id);
                    h.postDelayed(r, 15000);
                }
            };
            h.post(r);

            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
        //TOTO TU JE VELMI DISKUTABILNE
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void doStuff(final int id) {
        //TODO: Checkni pls ci je boxscore updatovany live alebo nie. Ak je tak ho mozes pouzit v IApiDefinition namiesto live feed
        // JA> V schedule je s gamepk aj online zapas s golmi - staci to pouzit
        ApiTools.getApi().getGame(id).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                if (sp.contains(Integer.toString(id))) {
                    int povodnyPocetGolovVZapase = sp.getInt(Integer.toString(id), 0);

                    //Z responsu zistit kolko eventov je teraz v zapase, t.j. ci uz zapas zacal.
                    //Dalej zistit ci su tam nejake eventy, ktore maju typ goal alebo ENDGAME (asi).
                    //AK sa zmenil pocet golov, tak posli notifikaciu ze padol gol aj s novym stavom

                    JsonObject data = response.body();
                    //pouzijem lastmatchmodel, aj ked to nie je pre toto robene, ale data mi stacia aj z neho
                    //List<LastMatchModel> livezapasy = new ArrayList<>();
                    //vytiahnem si zoznam
                    JsonArray zoznamZapasovZJsonu = data.get("dates").getAsJsonArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < zoznamZapasovZJsonu.size(); i++) {
                        //pouzijem lastmatchmodel, aj ked to nie je pre toto robene, ale data mi stacia aj z neho
                        LastMatchModel novyZapas = new LastMatchModel();
                        JsonObject zapasDate = zoznamZapasovZJsonu.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

                        JsonArray games = zapasDate.get("games").getAsJsonArray();
                        if (games.size() >= 1) {
                            JsonObject teams = games.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("teams").getAsJsonObject();

                            int golyHostia = teams.get("away").getAsJsonObject().get("score").getAsInt();
                            String timHostia = teams.get("away").getAsJsonObject().get("team").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();

                            int golyDomaci = teams.get("home").getAsJsonObject().get("score").getAsInt();
                            String timDomaci = teams.get("home").getAsJsonObject().get("team").getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();

                            if (golyDomaci + golyHostia != povodnyPocetGolovVZapase) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(GameChangeService.this, MatchNotification.class);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GameChangeService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                                createNotificationChannel();


                                final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GameChangeService.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                        .setContentTitle("GOAL")
                                        .setContentText(timDomaci + golyDomaci + " vs " + golyHostia + timHostia)
                                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

                                NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(GameChangeService.this);
                                nm.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());


                            }
                        }
                    }


                } else {
                    int povodnyPocetEventovVZapase = 0;
                    //Z responsu zistit kolko eventov je teraz v zapase, t.j. ci uz zapas zacal.
                    //Dalej zistit ci su tam nejake eventy, ktore maju typ goal alebo ENDGAME (asi).
                    //AK sa zmenil pocet golov, tak posli notifikaciu ze padol gol aj s novym stavom


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(GameChangeService.TAG, "Nebavi to ");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (h != null)
            h.removeCallbacks(r);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Name of the channel";
            String description = "Description of the channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

Run in Android Studio inform about errors:
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/01/03/Y6RS.png

or

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.luky.nhlvysledky, PID: 23251
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { (has extras) }
        at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1519)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1560)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1532)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:664)
        at com.example.luky.nhlvysledky.Future_matches.launchService(Future_matches.java:148)
        at com.example.luky.nhlvysledky.Future_matches.takeCareOfChanges(Future_matches.java:142)
        at com.example.luky.nhlvysledky.Future_matches.access$300(Future_matches.java:33)
        at com.example.luky.nhlvysledky.Future_matches$1$1.onClick(Future_matches.java:93)
        at com.example.luky.nhlvysledky.RecycleView.FutureMatchesHolder$1.onClick(FutureMatchesHolder.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: post the error, not an image. however, what sdk are you targeting?

Comment: Sorry, I edited post yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define which service you are starting in your intent.

```
getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), GameChangeService.class).putExtra(Tools.INTENT_EXTRA_ID,id));
```

You will also need to define your service in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".GameChangeService" />
```